# Apollo client GraphQL query: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: json, woocommerce, graphql, next.js, apollo

I'm using NextJS with WP WooCommerce to build my own site. By default, query result only return max 100 results, but I change it to 1000, this is not an issue.
When I make an request with query like this:

```
query MyQuery {
    products(first: 120) {
      nodes {
        id
        image {
          sourceUrl
        }
        name
        onSale
        productCategories {
          nodes {
            slug
          }
        }
        productTags {
          nodes {
            slug
          }
        }
        sku
        status
        totalSales
        type
        visibleProducts {
          nodes {
            slug
            isRestricted
          }
        }
        ... on VariableProduct {
          manageStock
          onSale
          price(format: RAW)
          regularPrice(format: RAW)
          salePrice(format: RAW)
          soldIndividually
          weight
          width
        }
        ... on ExternalProduct {
          onSale
          price(format: RAW)
          regularPrice(format: RAW)
          salePrice(format: RAW)
        }
        ... on SimpleProduct {
          price(format: RAW)
          regularPrice(format: RAW)
          salePrice(format: RAW)
          virtual
          weight
          width
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

That's ok. No problem.
But, when I want to load more product, 140 for example, I received a error message:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at https://domain.info/sub/wp-content/plugins/wp-graphql/src/Admin/GraphiQL/app/build/static/js/main.b7d08b5b.js?ver=5.6.2:1:597992
```

[image]

It look like overload JSON length or something like that? I dont understand. How can I solve this problem? I dont need pagination here because I wanna fetch all product (about ~150 items) for Static Site Genaration.

Comment: how a raw network response (from php) looks like? truncated?

Comment: Maybe something in your stack is cutting the response off or is sending wrong "Content-Length" header?

Comment: ... and SSG doesn't explain the 'give me all products in one step' need ... nobody wants to read 100+ products pages

Comment: @Herku I'm using ApolloClient in client and have no setting for "Content-Length" header. When I change 150 to 100 or 120, it's work. But with >140, it said `Unexpected end of JSON input`.

Comment: @xadm Yes no one read 100+ product at the time but I wanna fetch all product when generate static sites. 
For your question, in case `first: 140` or more, no response from php. Just throw error. Status code is 500 :(

Comment: headers are in browser dev tools, too -> NETWORK TAB - response (and request for POST `/graphql` request) headers ... 500 - no more details?

Comment: and still ... WHY? What for? specific use case ... next time you'll want only 210 or 532/1100/[whatever amount] of products ... bad reason/bad method?...probably you shoud extend WP GQL API using own plugin

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the `memory_limit` of your `php.ini` file.

---

Had the same issue when trying to fetch large numbers of products.

With debug logging enabled in the `debug.log` of WP I got:

```
[21-Oct-2022 08:25:22 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/meta.php on line 1189
```

So increasing did the job for me.